# Search with autofilter for any string from an array

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to filter a specific column in Excel. All cells contain one of the following strings: `Midpoint`, `Endpoint` or `Midpoint, Endpoint`. I would like to keep all cells that contain either the string `Midpoint` OR `Endpoint` (no matter what other strings are in the cell). I am using wildcards (`*`) and defined the following array as `search_criteria`: `Array("*Midpoint*", "*Endpoint*")`.

However, the behaviour is a bit odd and I do not understand it. Apparently, only rows are displayed where the cell value is either `Endpoint` or `Midpoint, Endpoint` and not as desired where the cell value contains either the string `Midpoint` or `Endpoint`.

```
Sub Oval5_Click()
column = 13
search_criteria = Array("*Midpoint*", "*Endpoint*") ''OR
'search_criteria = "*Midpoint*, *Endpoint*" ''AND
Worksheets("Overview").Activate
StartRow = 10
EndRow = 110
StartColumn = "A"
EndColumn = "Y"
Let Filterrange = StartColumn & StartRow & ":" & EndColumn & EndRow
ActiveSheet.Range(Filterrange).AutoFilter Field:=column, Criteria1:=search_criteria ', VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to *exclude* the rows that contain "Midpoint, Endpoint"? You'll need a different approach, because of the wildcards - `Midpoint, Endpoint` is a match for `*Midpoint*`. Said another way, the text "Midpoint, Endpoint" contains the string "Midpoint" - so that is not odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanky ou for your response! Any hint how a different approach could look like?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do - do you want all rows that contain "Midpoint" or "Endpoint", but *not both*?

Comment: A helper column is one of the other approaches.

Comment: @BigBen I would like to display all columns that contain either the string "Midpoint" or "Endpoint" regardless of what other strings are in the cell. Even if it is "blabla hello bla Midpoint blabla hello" ;-)

Comment: That's still not answering the question though, should the combination of Midpoint and Endpoint be *included* or *excluded*? "Regardless of what other strings are in the cell" is vague and does not clarify what I 99.9% assume, that the answer is *excluded*.

Comment: A helper column, as pointed out by @jvdv, is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Some things for you to consider:

- Avoid `Activate` but instead use explicit sheet references.
- Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) documentation on how to use the parameters of this function.

That being said, since all your cells contain one of three possible strings, maybe something along this line would work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Filterrange).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>*Midpoint, Endpoint*"
```

Comment: I set `search_criteria = Array("<>", "*Midpoint*", "*Endpoint*")` but that does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Jonas, that's completely different to the line of code I proposed.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thank you for your answer!! I came up with the line because I explicitly mentioned that I would like to search for items from an array so I thought your answer may be transferable to an array.

Comment: @Jonas, the way you are using the array, you should use the `xlFilterValues` operator > `Criteria1:=Array("*Midpoint*", "*Endpoint*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`. However, the wildcards will make sure you also filter the rows that contain either one of the two values. So effectively no rows get filtered out. If the proposed answer is not what you are trying to achieve, then your initial question need updating for more clarity.

Comment: See the comment underneath your initial question by @BigBen.